# Datastore vs Search API on pricing

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore, google-search-api

I have entities that I need to search through.
They can all easily fit into `Documents` within `Search API` (because all of it's properties need to be searchable) or within `Datastore` as `Entities` (I'm losing full search capabilities but it's not that important to me because I can work-through with `Datastore` rudimentary search).

So I can put my entities into `Search API` or `Datastore` so I can search and retrieve them later.

`Datastore` pricing is `$0.06 per 100,000 operations` where `Query` pricing is `1 read + 1 read per entity retrieved`.
`Search API` pricing is `$0.50 per 10K queries`.
The storage costs are the same.

If my search averages ~200 results per query that would be:

- `1 + 200 operations` or about `100,000/200=500 searches` for `$0.06` which is `$0,00012/per search` for Datastore
- 10K queries for `$0.50` or `$0,00005/per search` for Search API

Is the datastore that (2,4x) much more expensive or...?

Answer (score 2):

Default limit for Search API results is 20, and as from my experience using it in the past it becomes really slow with large limits. Datastore becomes more expensive only when you will return more than 80 results per page.

Search API will cost you `0.05 * 100 =` **$5** per one million any queries.

Datastore will cost you `80 * 0.06 =` **$4.8** per one million queries with limit 80.

Comment: I'm curious, why would Dastore queries become more expensive depending on the size of the returned results?

Comment: As I understand you will pay `100 * 0.06 = $6` per one million queries with limit 100. While in search API limiting number of results does not affect the price. In datastore, number of reads depends on number of retrieved entities.

Comment: Yeah, surely the cost of Datastore queries increases with the total number of retrieved entities but I've never read anywhere that retrieving 100 entities at the time would cost more than 80. If you retrieve 800 entities it should cost you the same, whether you retrieve 80 or 100 at the time, if I understand your point

Comment: From docs, the cost of datastore queries is `1 read + 1 read per entity retrieved`. So to retrieve 80 entities you will spend 81 read OPs and 101 OPs to retrieve 100. While it seems constant for search api.